# Linux Kernel : SKB shared info corruption

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-panic

I am seeing a kernel crash. 
It's because the `skb_shared_info` structure is corrupted for a skb buffer and because of that it is leading to kernel crash.

Can you please give me some directions on how to look at the issue further?

The problem above here is that shared info of the passed skb is corrupted: skb_shinfo (skb). Please see below.

```
(gdb) print *skb
$1 = {next = 0x0, prev = 0x0, tstamp = {tv64 = 0}, sk = 0xffff880071c23700, dev = 0x0, cb = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377", '\000' <repeats 31 times>, 
  cb2 = '\000' <repeats 103 times>, vrf = 0, src_class = 0, dst_class = 0, _skb_refdst = 0, sp = 0x0, len = 71, data_len = 0, mac_len = 0, hdr_len = 0, {csum = 0, {csum_start = 0, 
      csum_offset = 0}}, priority = 0, local_df = 0 '\000', cloned = 0 '\000', ip_summed = 0 '\000', nohdr = 0 '\000', nfctinfo = 0 '\000', pkt_type = 0 '\000', fclone = 0 '\000', 
  ipvs_property = 0 '\000', peeked = 0 '\000', nf_trace = 0 '\000', protocol = 0, destructor = 0xffffffff817615b0 <unix_destruct_scm>, nfct = 0x0, skb_iif = 0, rxhash = 0, vlan_proto = 0, 
  vlan_tci = 0, queue_mapping = 0, pfmemalloc = 0 '\000', ooo_okay = 0 '\000', l4_rxhash = 0 '\000', wifi_acked_valid = 0 '\000', wifi_acked = 0 '\000', no_fcs = 0 '\000', head_frag = 0 '\000', 
  encapsulation = 0 '\000', {napi_id = 0, dma_cookie = 0}, secmark = 0, {mark = 0, dropcount = 0, reserved_tailroom = 0}, inner_protocol = 0, inner_transport_header = 0, inner_network_header = 0, 
  inner_mac_header = 0, transport_header = 65535, network_header = 0, mac_header = 65535, tail = 71, end = 128, head = 0xffff88035f280ff8 'k' <repeats 200 times>..., 
  data = 0xffff88035f280ff8 'k' <repeats 200 times>..., truesize = 896, users = {counter = 1}}

(gdb) p *( ((struct skb_shared_info *) 0xFFFF88035F281078))
$2 = {nr_frags = 107 'k', tx_flags = 107 'k', gso_size = 27499, gso_segs = 27499, gso_type = 27499, frag_list = 0x6b6b6b6b6b6b6b6b, hwtstamps = {hwtstamp = {tv64 = 7740398493674204011}, 
    syststamp = {tv64 = 7740398493674204011}}, ip6_frag_id = 1802201963, dataref = {counter = 1802201963}, destructor_arg = 0x6b6b6b6b6b6b6b6b, uarg = {callback = 0x6b6b6b6b6b6b6b6b, 
    ctx = 0x6b6b6b6b6b6b6b6b, desc = 7740398493674204011}, ubufs = {1802201963, 1802201963, 1802201963, 1802201963, 1802201963, 1802201963, 1802201963}, bufpool_id = 1802201963, frags = {{page = {
        p = 0x6b6b6b6b6b6b6b6b}, page_offset = 1802201963, size = 1802201963} <repeats 17 times>}}
```

The number of fragments (nr_frags) present in the skb shared info is very far away from the MAX value which is 16 and we see the frag_list is also having junk values.